# xml get width and set to android:height

Tags: android, xml, width

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height=" "
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Here's the thing, lets say i have this `LinearLayout` that has a width of `match_parent`, so the width of the `LinearLayout` depends on the width of the device. What i dont know is how could i set the `android:layout_height=" "` value to correspond on the value of the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` so i could have a **Square** `LinearLayout` i know i can do this using `LayoutParams` but is there a way to do it on `xml`? Thank you guys..

Comment: hardcode both height and width with your desired or do it progrmatically..

Answer (score 1):

First get screen width

```
Display mDisplay = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width  = mDisplay.getWidth();
int height = mDisplay.getHeight();
```

Set Size to Layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutID);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = width;
params.width = width;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

In XML:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:id="@+id/LayoutID"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: this will definitely help but isnt it possible to do in xml alone?

Comment: As u want to set height of layout for all device. You can set hard coded width value in values folder & can set it in xml.